# SQL Server connection string error cannot connect

Tags: c#, sql-server

This is my connection string

I have added double `\\` for the unrecognized escape sequence in vs 2019

```
SqlConnection db = new SqlConnection("Server=localhost\\DESKTOP-8QL52AL\\ASADI; Database=atm;  Integrated Security=True;");
db.Open();
```

> Error at line -26 check your server name or check your SQL Server is configured for remote connections

[image: SQL SERVER CONNECTION IMAGE]

Comment: You have given a host twice in the connection string. Remove either one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You server/instance name is all wrong:

```
"Server=localhost\\DESKTOP-8QL52AL\\ASADI;
```

You can **either** have

1. just the server name (or IP address) when connecting to the default, unnamed instance on your machine

   ```
    Server=DESKTOP-8QL52AL
   ```
2. or you can have the server name and an instance name, if you're connecting to a named instance

   ```
    Server=DESKTOP-8QL52AL\\ASADI
   ```

And in both cases, you *can* replace the actual physical machine name with `localhost` to connect to the local machine (without specifying its explicit name):

```
    Server=localhost
    Server=localhost\\ASADI
```

but you **CANNOT** have `localhost` *AND* your explicit machine name `DESKTOP-8QL52AL` in a single connection string - that just doesn't make any sense and isn't supported.

Answer (score 0):

If the SQL server is on the local machine and you only have 1 sql instance installed

> "Server=localhost; Database=atm;  Integrated Security=True;"

if its SQL EXPRESS use

> "Server=localhost\SQLEXPRESS; Database=atm;  Integrated Security=True;"

Answer (score 0):

Basic Sql Server connection string syntax:

```
connetionString="Data Source=ServerName;Initial Catalog=DatabaseName;User ID=UserName;Password=Password"
```

If you have a named instance of SQL Server, you'll need to add that as well.

```
"Server=localhost\sqlexpress"
```